# Connect to SQLite using ODBC without register database

Tags: c++, sqlite, odbc

Is it possible to connect to SQLite in C++ and using ODBC API without register the database in ODBC?

I have code that uses ODBC talking to databases and don't want to rewrite for using SQLite and don’t want to register new ODBC connections.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to do it without any code changes using [sqliteodbc](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).

Comment: This is a nice tool.  It installs the ODBC driver for you and after installing it, you simply configure a DSN that connects to a file.

Comment: @Rev aftef install `sqliteodbc`, i write this demo: http://pastebin.com/apFk0w8J

But VBE pop-up error message:
`Run-time error '424': Object required`

How to connect to a sqlite file?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, use one of the following connection strings:

```
Driver=SQLite ODBC Driver;Database=full-path-to-db;...
Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=full-path-to-db;...
```

Long answer: The readme file included with the sqliteodbc driver covers the methods for connecting, using a DSN-less connection string.

See http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html