# Is there a way to run SQL Reports on a SQLite Database?

Tags: sqlite, ssrs-2008

We used to use TFS, but have recently moved to another bug tracker.  We also have a few reports that we ran on the work items from TFS, and would like to do the same with the new bug tracker that uses SQLite.

EDIT:
The bug tracker is Trac.

Comment: do you mean a kind of wrapper that exposes SQLite files as a DBMS motor, so you can connect from elsewhere (your reports), with minimal changes?

Comment: @Luis, yes.  I have some reports and want to either be able to run the SSRS on the new database file, or have some sort of thing that will let me connect to the data, so I won't have to recreate the reports from scratch.

Comment: i do not know any. i will follow the question as you. perhaps you can reformulate the way i asked to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does an SQLite ODBC Driver solve the problem?  see:
[Connect to SQLite using ODBC without register database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639899/connect-to-sqlite-using-odbc-without-register-database)